# SQL Query to find record where one of the composite primary keys should be Max against other composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, composite

Following is my table:

```
PatientID|VisitID|Date|Accident|Diagnosis|Doctor
  1      |    1  |    |        |         | 
  1      |    2  |    |        |         |
  1      |    3  |    |        |         |
```

Both `PatientID` and `VisitID` are composite primary keys. Now I want to show only the last record. In other words where `PatientID`=`1` and `VisitID`=Maximum.

So what would the query be?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `VisitID` is sequential:

```
select top 1 * from yourTable
where PatientID=@patientID
order by VisitID desc
```

Where: `@patientID` is a parameter (which, in your example, is `1`)

Comment: Thanks very much for ur answer.But I tried the following nested query, as objective was to only show the single record having VisitID=3


Select * from tblAccident where PatientID=1 AND VisitNo=(Select Max(VisitNo)from tblAccident where PatientID =1

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman that's good. you may post that as an answer to your question as well, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

One of my seniors in the office told the following query, that meets my objective perfectly.

```
select * 
  from tblAccident 
 where PatientID = 1 
   and VisitNo = ( Select Max(VisitNo) from tblAccident where PatientID = 1 )
```